# Android soundpool error ocuring while i try to write something in login form that i have made in android

Tags: android, web-services, audio, soundpool

when i run my simple login app in android it runs perfectly, but when i try to insert data in it using webservice, it gives error:

`" soundpool could not open: /system/media/audio/ui/keypressStandard.ogg"`,

I just want to know why this error occurs and what this error shows?

like: is this a code issue?
             or
      it is problem due to web service?

Comment: it occurs because something is wrong

Comment: mihail i have asked what this error show, where is expected error occurring, as my app doesn't crashes, it only gives this error when i try to enter data in form

Answer (score 0):

this error says, soundpool is not able to play this file,or may be the file is curropt,or is not readable.
i have also get a list of quick search regarding this issue, and found this:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58113

Comment: its not necessary actually, as i am not using any sound acitvity, i havve answered my question after resolving it. thanks any way for your helping concern.

Answer (score 0):

My error was due to calling network web service from UI page of android, while android doesn't allow this after honeycomb, now i removed this conflict by using ~[strictmode]~ method and using Async technique, one can also try this by using thread management so that main activity in android avoid network calls.